# Editing questions: dos and don'ts

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette, suggested-edits

**What is the etiquette for editing questions?** How much is it OK to modify? What are the guidelines and what are the limits?

I am concerned that once a question has been edited, the difficulties facing the initial user may not be as conspicuous because the editor may have inadvertently filled in some critical conceptual gaps in the question.

Specifically:

1. **Data sets** are sometimes presented in different ways including JPEG screenshots. How should they be reformatted, in particular to avoid presuming R familiarity or preference? On this issue I got moderator guidance from @whuber advising to format them as text (usually comma delimited), or else include the data in the answer.
2. Should **plots** be always left untouched?  Beyond subjective, aesthetic considerations, perhaps some subtle change in the presentation or the data may occur that defeats the purpose of the OP.
3. Do you all agree that improving the **grammar** to make the question understandable is an OK reason for an edit?
4. Is reformatting with $\LaTeX{}$ to beautify equations OK without exceptions?

Comment: Hi Antoni. This seems to be our best meta thread on editing questions and other questions are starting to get closed as duplicates of it. Nick's answer does indeed provide excellent guidance. However, the question is a bit long and its first part is more of an introduction. Given the question's popularity, I thought perhaps you might want to condense it to make it more to the point ("What is the etiquette for editing questions?"). (I guess if you prefer I could suggest an edit and you roll back if you don't like it.) Feel free to leave it as is if you find it more appropriate. Just an idea!

Comment: @amoeba It would be greatly appreciated it if you edited this question. There is no question on my mind that the changes would be an improvement. So please, please go ahead... Just don't decompose it into eigenvectors :-)

Comment: I gave it a shot.

Comment: **If a user edits a post to include "(Solved)" or similar in the title, I will make fun of them in the comments.**

Answer (score 31):

This is a series of side-notes to @Glen_b's excellent answer.

*The editing process*

**Editing is a public service.** Even some small edits can just clean up a post and make it easier for everyone to read, which is a positive contribution. Often an edit can change a question that looks too messy to wade through to one that looks readable. Editing can and should help the OP, who should get more and quicker attention (and, although this is a side-effect, who should also get feedback on their presentation for future questions). It helps others too.

**Editing does not impart a moral judgment.** We can't confidently and consistently  distinguish between over-hasty, lazy presentation and someone struggling with one, two or even all three of a second language; statistics they really don't understand; and a medium that is unfamiliar. That said, I will on occasion comment firmly that a question (or answer) is just too messy to be worth anyone's time to edit. If the OP isn't able or willing to fix the presentation, then that is the end of the story: we are all volunteers here and there is no obligation to be infinitely helpful.

**Editing even one small thing requires a careful decision.** It will bump the question momentarily to the top of the active list. Some people are irritated to re-open a post of interest to find one minute change. But even threads that have seen many posts can carry errors worth correcting. Nevertheless, for this and other reasons, it is good advice that if you edit, edit everything that you spot as deserving change, so as to make the edit worthwhile.

*Editing titles, tags and commentary*

**Editing just the title can be valuable.** Posters can be especially blind to typos in the title. Considering that titles are key for later searches, even trivial misspellings can be a nuisance. It's common that titles are too long and/or carry useless words (*please help*; *question about*; *how to analyse my data*). On the other hand, sometimes you need to flag to posters that they should think up a better title themselves. (It's a fact of life in a forum that some members use eccentric or inadequately informative titles as a criterion for what to ignore, so improving them may seem a disservice too.)

**Editing the question itself can help.** Cut out wording such as "My question is" or "The question I would like to ask is". Feel free to add a question mark when needed grammatically or to emphasise a precise and concise question, say by isolating it as a single paragraph or by recasting it in bold. If you can't identify a clear question at all, that is cause for comment rather than an attempt to rewrite the post.

**Editing the tags on a post can be valuable**. Posters often omit tags that are highly relevant (e.g. `data-transformation`) or specify tags that are fairly useless (e.g. `mathematical-statistics` for almost any post). A sensitive exception is the `self-study` tag, which ideally should be added only by the original poster to show self-awareness of the condition. Otherwise, disagreement over tags is easy enough to fix, so it is fine to edit if you are confident that you can improve tags.

**Edits should remove greetings** (at the beginning of a post) **or signatures** (at the end) **and any material that looks irrelevant to the question**. That includes polite (or even not so polite) expressions of how confused the poster is, how much time they have already spent working on the problem, how grateful they will be for an answer and (especially) how urgent or important the question is. Other comments that can usually be cut include claims that the question is quick, easy or simple: sometimes such claims are just wrong, and when they are right they don't illuminate the question.

**Edits should focus attention on the technical content of a question**, rather than the human side. In a busy world, being able to read that content quickly and easily is a bonus for all. (I leave open whether it's a benefit that editing sometimes makes it clearer that there is no underlying precise and concise question.)

*Editing issues with statistics*

**Edits can change presentation in any aspect, but as far as possible should only clarify, not change, the statistical content** that defines the question being asked. Aspects of presentation to edit can include grammar, spelling, punctuation, and other styling of text, math, code or data.

**Edits should not change strange or even incorrect uses of statistical terms, or any other dubious statistical content, even for obvious errors**. Naturally, you should only change the language if you are confident that you are right (or have better taste or style...)! (Don't worry too much about this; a mistaken edit can be reversed.)

There is, as often, a small tension between the immediate, short-term aim of helping the original poster and the ultimate, longer-term aim of building an archive of high quality answered questions that should be of interest or use to many readers (in many cases, long after a poster may have disappeared from the forum). But **any errors, omissions, or confusion in the statistical content of a question are likely to be part of the OP's problem and should be left as posted**. Someone who edits a question may not intend to answer it, but can help by publicising difficult points in comments. For example, *you say that you want to apply multivariate regression, but you only have one response variable, so I think you mean multiple regression*.

**Edits can introduce or improve mark-up of mathematics, code and data, but should not change even poor notation choices, which could be part of the problem.** I would correct trivia, as when someone has posted $\beta2$, but it's evident that they mean $\beta_2$, but if in doubt, do not edit, but rather comment. *There seems to be a square missing from your variance formula.*

*Editing graphs and code*

**Edits should rarely replace someone's graph**. But here is a further  situation where that does seems right: when presented with a very crude hand-drawn graph that someone has scanned or photographed, you may  without loss be able to do a much better job.

**Any editing of code should be done with caution**, especially if incorrect or inappropriate code may be part of the problem. In such cases answers should explain and suggest ways to improve or correct the code. There are limited exceptions. For example, long lines of code are awkward or annoying to read if they require horizontal scrolling. Editing the code to fit within the visible question window -- using any essentially cosmetic change -- is a small public service. You can also insert blank lines to divide the code into smaller coherent blocks. But you need to be sure that your edits do not change the meaning of the code or affect whether it runs as written. When in doubt, do not touch.

**Appendix: common statistics typos**

This is a list of some common typos arising in statistical literature.

Seekers of *causal* links should never be *casual* in reading proofs.

Software: Proprietary names include MS Excel, MATLAB (although to avoid shouting Matlab is, IMHO, good practice) and emphatically Stata (not STATA).

**The following statisticians' and scientists' surnames end with "s", so watch out.**

Thus whatever is
attributed to them is tagged with (e.g.) Jeffreys or Jeffreys', but not
Jeffrey's.

Frank Ephraim Grubbs 1913–2000

Larry Vernon Hedges

Harold Jeffreys 1891-1989 (not to be confused with William Hamilton Jefferys III 1940=)

Colin Lingwood Mallows 1930-2023

Brian W. Matthews 1938- (Matthews correlation)

John P. Mills fl.1926 (Mills ratio)

Robert Hough Somers 1929-2004 (Somers' $d$)

Stanley Smith Stevens 1906-1973 (scales of measurement: NOIR)

Herbert Arthur Sturges 1882-1958 (Sturges' rule for histograms)

Samuel Stanley Wilks 1906-1964 (but note Martin Bradbury Wilk 1922-2013)

Peter Ross Winters 1929-2018 (Holt-Winters)

Frank Yates 1902-1994

**Here are some other surnames that are often mangled in writing.**

Ole Eiler Barndorff-Nielsen 1935-2022

Carlo Emilio Bonferroni 1892–1960

Carl Harald Cramér 1893-1985 (NB accent)

Student 1876-1937 was William Sealy Gosset (not Gossett)

Richard A. Leibler 1914-2003 (not Liebler)

George Pólya 1887-1985 (NB accent)

Alfréd Rényi 1921-1970 (NB accents)

Henry Scheffé 1907-1977 (NB accent)

Gideon Schwarz 1933-2007 (not Schwartz) (BIC)

Hermann Amandus Schwarz 1843-1921 (not Schwartz) (Cauchy-Schwarz)

Leonard Henry Caleb Tippett 1902–1985 (not Tippet)

Bernard Lewis Welch 1911-1989 but Roy Elmer Welsch 1943-

Frank Wilcoxon 1892–1965 (not Wilcox or Wilcoxin)

Charles P. Winsor 1895-1951 (not Windsor; hence Winsorize not Windsorize)

**Some people cited in statistics share surnames. Were they relatives?**

Bernoulli family. There were lots of them.

Playfair family. John Playfair (1748-1819) was brother of William
Playfair (1759-1823).

Pearson family. Karl Pearson (1857-1936) was father of Egon Sharpe Pearson (1896-1980).

Coxes. Gertrude Mary Cox (1900-1978) was unrelated to David Roxbee Cox
(1924-2022).

Kendalls. Maurice George Kendall (1907-1983) was unrelated to David George Kendall (1918-2007).

**Some bad Greek and Latin is common.**

"polychotomous" is bad Greek, probably arising from a misunderstanding
of "dichotomous", which is "dicho" + "tomous", not "di" + "chotomous".
"polytomous" is better.

One criterion, two or more criteria. So never "a criteria".

"data" in Latin means "given things" and is a plural. What this implies
for modern languages is discussable. See also comments below.

"strata" in Latin is another plural. "stratum" is the singular.

Some people want to insist that "heteroskedastic" and "homoskedastic"
are the correct spellings. (There was no "c" in ancient Greek.) This
argument was published in *Econometrica*.  Oddly enough, the spellings
"heteroscedastic" and "homoscedastic" are due to Karl Pearson, who was
no enemy of "k"; he changed his own name from Carl and founded the
journal *Biometrika*. Fans of "k" should promise to write of
mikroekonomics and makroekonomics on the grounds that all the pertinent
roots of those words are all Greek too. See an entire dedicated thread [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153526/why-are-there-two-spellings-of-heteroskedastic-or-heteroscedastic).

**Finally, here is some not yet idiomatic English (prejudices ahead).**

The expressions "a data" (to mean a dataset) and "a code" (to mean a
program) are not yet part of standard English. They are already
collectives.

Using "skew" to mean "bias" is unfortunate, but general English usage has shifted strongly that way in recent years.

On the grey area between statistical terms we know (and sometimes love) and uses or abuses of the same words within and beyond statistics and science, see also the thread [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202879/what-misused-statistical-terms-are-worth-correcting).

Comment: Based on your earlier comments in chat I was keen to see you post -- especially because there's a few aspects where we differ. However, this is a better post even than I had hoped to see, with many good points and useful suggestions. It's important that people be able to see it here.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks! I don't think we differ much at all. So far as I can gather, you lean towards fixing technical side issues and changing graphs to improve presentation a little more than I do.

Comment: Yes, it's a small difference on a few items,  but I think it's important to get a sense of those differences. I'll be considering those sort of edits more carefully, for one thing.

Comment: Re common name mangling: lower case gauss, and markov spring to mind. :) Also with respect to applying ancient Greek or Latin orthography to contemporary (statistical) English appears to me to be akin to the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Comment: I am favour of recognising the great people at whose feet we sit and on whose shoulders we stand. It would be interesting to learn of any cases where family names should not receive an initial capital for some different reason. For no good reason, I find references to cox regression and box-cox transformations particularly painful.

Comment: IMHO, the most egregious common misspellings on CV are ["Wilcox"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22wilcox+test%22) and ["Wilcoxin"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=wilcoxin) for Frank Wilcoxon.  The former is an original sin of the `R` development team while the latter must just be ignorance, fueled perhaps by the absence of the "on" in the `R` terminology... .  Fortunately, these have been fixed in 98% of the cases.  (Another awful misspelling is "Normal" for "Gauss," but that one left the barn long ago :-).

Comment: @whuber Thanks for Wilcoxon; I've often muttered at Wilcox coming straight from an R function name (it's incidental that Wilcoxon also had a coauthor called Wilcox). I've also added Winsor, after seeing yet another Windsorize on this site.

Comment: On Cramer vs Cramér; I (somewhat) recently saw some disputation on the correctness of the accent. I really wish I could locate it again so I could link to it.

Comment: The accent is there in his 1946 book from Princeton UP, which I understand to be a reprint of the Swedish version from 1945.

Comment: Charles Paine Winsor.

Answer (score 22):

[Just to make clear, though my answers should always be read this way: this is personal opinion]

You don't need to have any intention of answering a question to edit it.

> the difficulties facing the initial user may not be as conspicuous because the editor may have inadvertently filled in some critical conceptual gaps in the OP.

Where feasible, it's important to have a question and answer that will be understood by and be useful to more people.

Mostly you should lean toward letting the OP's phrasing stand, but you can certainly encourage the OP to clarify. While some people would lean toward *never* fixing misconceptions in the question, if it's a side issue to the main question *and* fixing it is likely to clarify that misconception for the OP it may be okay. (It can sometimes be hard to be sure, though.)

The concern you mentioned is certainly possible so if you do edit, care must be taken - and you can always invite the OP to change anything back.

> In the case of plots, and beyond subjective, aesthetic considerations, perhaps some subtle change in the presentation or the data may occur that defeats the purpose of the OP.

Such things are always a small risk with edits. If you're aware of the possibility, it's unlikely to be a major problem. Note that edits can be rolled back.

> How should data points be posted to avoid presuming R familiarity or preference?

Certainly avoid editing to make anything *R*-specific; if it's already R-specific that's different. It's perfectly possible to edit to produce a cleanly-formatted ASCII table, for example, which will copy-paste (or easily be read) into a wide variety of packages.

e.g. something formatted like this:

```
    A     B
    4     2
    4    10
    7     4
    7    22
    8    16
    9    10
```

... is not R-specific but will read straight into R with a copy-paste (type `OPdata=read.table(stdin(),header=TRUE)` then paste, press Enter and you have a data frame; or just read from `clipboard` rather than `stdin`)

So: plain ASCII text in a standard form (space delimited or comma-delimited, compatible with CSV) is desirable -- these can be read by almost anything. This is uniformly better that an image of numbers (since it contains the same information but can be used by answerers) ... but be *very* careful you don't change the data!

> On this issue I got moderator guidance from @whuber advising to format them as text (usually comma delimited), or else include the data in the answer.

It's sensible advice; I'd add space-delimited to the mix of what's fine.

> Should plots be always left untouched?

I don't have enough context to know what things you're proposing to fix, but *usually* you wouldn't alter a plot. *Always* is too strong.

There are some situations where I have edited a plot. One example is where there's a small plot with *gigantic* amounts of white-space around it (a plot smaller than 1/10 the size of a standard page (A4 or 8.5x11), say 3x2.5 inches sitting in a field of white pixels the size of a page. In that case I cut out almost all the white space.

> Do you all agree that improving the grammar to make the question understandable is an OK reason for an edit in some cases?

Yes, almost always.

> Is reformatting with latex to beautify equations OK without exceptions?

Nearly always, it's a good thing to do.

But *without exception*? That's hard to say, since exceptions may be things we haven't thought of. But in this case I can think of a few possible exceptions.

i. If I expect a post will move to SO I try to avoid LaTeX.

ii. If an equation can as easily be read as pseudocode (e.g. can very easily be turned into say a formula in R if left as is) I'm less inclined to edit it because there's another way to use it as it stands.

Your question is filled with requests for absolutes. That's not going to happen. Don't look for ironclad rules here. Just act sensibly, change things in ways that will clearly improve the post for as many people as you can, but with respect for the OP's intent.

If one is to edit (which is a very good thing to do), it's necessary to accept that:

1. You will occasionally make mistakes (of judgement, say)
2. Even when you act in very sensible ways, people will disagree occasionally; there can be legitimate difference of opinion

Don't get too bothered about these things unless there seem to be a lot of problems, in which case you may need to attempt to move your expectations toward the community norms more. Mistakes are not irretrievable -- as the saying goes, it's not rocket surgery[.](http://www.waywordradio.org/rocket_surgery/)

---

Oh, and definitely put me down in the "the data *were*" column. "Datum" is singular, "data" is a plural noun.

Comment: Glen, Thank you for your answer. I tried the code and I got the following: `OPdata=read(stdin(),header=TRUE)
Error: could not find function "read"`

Comment: @Antoni thanks, that was meant to be `read.table`. I believe I originally typed read.table but I likely screwed it up during editing of my answer before posting.

Comment: I have a vague idea what rocket science is. However I would be interested to know what is rocket surgery?

Comment: @mpiktas Two common sayings are "it's not brain surgery" and "it's not rocket science", both of which mean the same thing. Mixing the two is amusing in a silly way, possibly implying the speaker (or writer in this case) is stupid. See [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rocket+surgery) or [TvTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThisAintRocketSurgery) or [A Way With Words](http://www.waywordradio.org/rocket_surgery/)

Comment: Just as I suspected :)

Comment: The former saying has received (what shall I say?) a renewed boost recently with the ventures of a former brain surgeon outside brain surgery.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I've watched those ventures with some amusement. It would be even funnier if the eventual outcome weren't so serious.

Comment: On data as singular and plural. _Data_ clearly has a Latin root as a plural, but language changes and need not be logically consistent. Older folks who grew up writing down each value, adding them up and so forth are more likely to think of their data as plural than younger people for whom the data is [sic] just a single entity handled on the computer; and indeed the data can be both. Latin plurals can become singulars (who says "the agenda are long"?) and words can be both singular and plural (there's a hair on your shirt; I need to get my hair cut).

Comment: I still usually prefer to say and write for myself "the data show", "the data are", but it's far, far too late to eradicate the other form. "The data is consistent with a linear pattern": I find myself saying such things too. But I still cringe at "I have a data" which I have only noticed in the last few years, but I can't put my finger on why. I think it's just that one form is idiomatic around me and the other isn't, so it's all probably food for the sociologists.

Comment: Similarly on the word _code_ as anything from a few lines in some language to a self-contained program. "I have some code"; "the code isn't working" sound fine but "I have a code" doesn't sound at all right and I tend to edit it out. That statement may well seem utterly parochial, all the way down to my perception of what is said among my own peer group of some British academics. But editing what is not widely idiomatic to what is widely idiomatic can be important too.

Comment: Declaration of war: I always edit out _i_ for _I_ and _gonna_ and _wanna_.

Comment: I agree with your particular points there.

Comment: *Data* is so clearly defective as a count noun - the queerness of "How many data are there?", "We collected sixty data", "This datum is an outlier", & the like is apparent, I think, to native English speakers - that preservation of its grammatical plurality can hardly be defended on any other grounds than a general principle of linguistic conservatism. Though I can't quite bring myself to treat it as a  (grammatically singular) mass noun, I therefore don't correct it when editing others' posts.

Comment: @NickCox: "I have a data" is still wrong under the view of *data* as a mass noun that justifies "the data shows". The same with *code*, I think.

Comment: @Scortchi You may have a golden thread there out of the maze. But we can say "I saw a crowd" and "The crowd was large". So, in such cases, _a_ and _the_ both seem idiomatic. What's the difference?

Comment: @NickCox: *Crowd* is a collective noun rather than a mass noun. You can't say "I saw a water" or "I saw a cutlery".

Comment: But _crowd_ to me maps one-to-one to _data_. Why are _data_ a mass? It seems quite arbitrary to deny that they are a collective. I can't rebut any grammarians' distinctions here, but these are rules taught by grammarians to each other that have no hope of influencing standard usage. (I was taught in school by graduates in English to avoid split infinitives as a indisputable imperative, only to learn years later that professionals regard that taboo as ridiculous nonsense.)

Comment: Is "I have some data" correct?

Comment: @Andre Yes, in my book -- I think it would be correct whether you're one to consider data to be countable (like peas or cows; *I saw two cows* vs *I saw some cows*) or an uncountable/mass noun (like rice or sand; *I ate some rice*). On the other hand, English will do what it will do, and in time "data" will almost certainly become seen as singular by a majority -- and all the students that I see write "datas" presently will become right, and fogies like me will just have to deal with having become archaic. Indeed data has been headed that way for a while (and agenda with it).  ... ctd

Comment: ctd... As far as I see, few people have said datum or agendum in a long time.

Comment: _Datum_ retains a specific meaning in surveying and geodesy. For example, land surface altitudes in Britain are reported relative to Ordnance Datum. But within statistics stricter sense I don't think I've heard the word used in recent years, except facetiously. Data point is often useful and (often deliberately) matches the geometric or graphical meaning perfectly.

Comment: I should also have added *erratum* to the list of dying singular forms. I hear "an errata" occasionally.

Comment: I think "an errata" is more nearly just a mistake. Ditto "a criteria", "a phenomena" (switching to Greek from Latin).

Comment: @NickCox: Grammarians in this case are trying to explain what's happened to *data* by observing how we use it rather than to stipulate how we ought to use it, & in many ways our use of *data* follows the pattern of our use of mass nouns. I'd imagine knowledge of Latin was originally widespread among those few who had occasion to use the word: later, as *data* waxed & Latin waned, for many the *only* clue pointing to its plurality came from verbal inflection; no surprise that some started to assimilate it to a familiar pattern. Singular *data* was a tragedy waiting to happen.

Comment: Of course *data* had a tragic flaw: the lack of a dominant, unambiguous criterion for individuation. We can, & often do, talk glibly of "data" without a clear notion of what a single datum would be (is a point on a scatter-plot a datum? or two data?). Though attempted explanations of grammatical categories in terms of semantics seem to throw up as many exceptions as regularities, there's a tendency for mass nouns to share this lack, & I feel that some sense of *data*'s kinship to *news*, *information*, & the like played a part in the change. Even careful writers who treat ...

Comment: ... *data* as plural when conjugating the verb of which it's the subject often prefer "much data" to "many data" & "less data" to "fewer data". (In fact, Glen_b, you seem to be one of them!) Taking this view, we should expect to see "data is" replacing "data are", but  "a data" or "datas" will remain rare solecisms. In fine smoothing out one irregularity - an apparent mass noun's being grammatically plural - introduces another - a Latin plural's being grammatically singular. I think reasonable people can differ as to whether it's worth it.

Comment: @NickCox: I've garnered "how much data are missing", "there are now too much data", "how much data are needed", "less data are likely to be required", & "very little data are missing" from CV posts by users whose English would nearly always pass muster with conservatives - one can't imagine any of them writing "how much apples are missing" &c. (You seem to be a paragon of consistency by the way.) This suggests to me that singular *data* is exerting an attraction, though I suppose it could be argued that it's merely infectious.

Comment: @Scortchi Very interesting. I'll take the compliment "paragon of consistency" and run! But as my opening comment admitted, I find myself sometimes using _data_ singular in conversation, but I tend to edit it out of my own prose, just as Yeah is often what I say, but Yes is always what I write. Orthogonally to all this I often use _data set_ or even _dataset_ as a way of avoiding solecism. The last I learned from Stata documentation, disliked for a while, but now regard as a positive solution for talking about the data when considered as a singular whole.

Comment: I am the same; I will use it as singular when talking, but I try to fix it in my writing

Comment: It seems I've lost my long battle against "codes"; *code* for instructions to a computer has been a mass noun for considerably more than half a century, but I now regularly see "codes" even for just a few lines of code. This one makes me feel distinctly dispepsic on the best of days, so I seem to have picked my hill there.